# Asp.net HTTP Handler Session handling

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler

In case we maintain session in HTTP handler, will that be shared between all requests to website or its scope is different for each request, for the same session variable.

Just wanted to understand the lifecycle of Session variable in case of the handler.

Comment: Its the same context that will be shared with that of the rest of the application.

Comment: So, In case we have create a named session it will remain accessible to all other user sessions too?